# Win7 Command Line piping

Tags: windows, command-line, pipe

I want to know why in the command line prompt this happens.

I have a script `fileX.cmd` which is one single line of text:

```
@echo dir
```

If I do

```
C:\Users\Dogfood>fileX.cmd | cmd
```

This will show all the files in the directory but...

```
C:\Users\Dogfood>type fileX.cmd | cmd
```

does not.  The command prompt opens a new cmd but asks me "`More?`"

Why aren't the contents of fileX.cmd piped into the cmd to the right of the pipe
the same way as the first line? (i.e. `fileX.cmd | cmd`)

Answer (score 0):

The pipe to cmd `| cmd` will execute any commands in its input stream.

- In the first case the input stream will contain the output of `fileX.cmd`, namely `dir`, and this is what the `| cmd` will execute.
- in the second case, the input stream will contain `@echo dir`, so you should see just the text `dir`.

I get `More?` if there is no new-line on the end of the command in `fileX.cmd`. The reason for the difference is that the primary shell will take the command as complete when EOF is reached, whereas the cmd at the end of the pipe expects complete lines. If you want an explanation of why this should be, you'll have to ask Microsoft.

(By the way, your description refers to `fileX`, not `fileX.cmd`, and you say it contains a single line, whereas I suspect it contains an incomplete line.)

Comment: very good AFH.  I've got it straight finally!!

Answer (score -1):

You need to remember piping takes the *output* of the first part of the command and passes that to the next command.

Lets take `fileX.cmd | cmd` and break it down:

filex.cmd = @echo dir

If we type @echo dir from the command line, we see the output as `dir`.  Echo simply outputs what comes after the echo command.  The output isnt executed, just displayed.

typing filex.cmd from the command prompt and hitting enter gives us the output `dir`.  This is no different than the previous statement, just that the command is in a batch/cmd file.

If we add the `| cmd`, then the results we see are different, we get a directory listing.  Why?  Because the output of filex.cmd is `dir` and we are passing `dir` to the command prompt, which takes that output and executes it, giving us a directory listing.

So why doesnt the second command do the same thing?  The reason is, you are using the `type` command.  `Type` displays the text to the screen.  If your directory listing is short, it would have worked.  However, your directory listing scrolls off the screen, therefore the `type` command pauses the output and asks if you want `more?`.  That question, `more?` is now the output and being passed to the command prompt.

Note, if your directory listing was shorter, `type` would not ask for more and the command would have worked how *you* would have expected it.  Try the same commands in a directory that only contains a few directories and files and you will see the difference.

Comment: So using fileX.cmd right after the prompt or cmd fileX simply performs the echo and I end up with "dir".  Then that gets piped and out come the files.                                                  Type fileX or type fileX.cmd shows the contents and does NOT !! echo.  "echo dir" goes through the pipe and results in "dir".      A solution I have now is to use : type fileX.cmd | cmd | cmd

Comment: That is not where the `More?` is coming from: `type` precedes any directory listing. See my answer.